# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column with msql table in foreign language

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've built an rails app that is connected to a mysql database which as its table names and columns in Spanish. I've made models representing the tables with English names and put inside each model `self.table_name = "table_name_in_spanish"` to translate table to the model name so that Rails convention doesn't get broken. With that in mind, I have a model `Ad` and a model `AdCopy` which contains multiple descriptions for the `Ad` model. When I want to get a list of these descriptions for one ad I do the following inside `rails c`:

I first assign the ad to variable:

```
pry(main)> ad = Ad.last
  Ad Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `anuncios`.* FROM `anuncios` ORDER BY `anuncios`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Ad:0x00007ff8dc45e2f0
 id: 1241,
 empresa: "Example Ad",
 tel: "555 555 555",
 [...]
```

Then try to access the ad copies (descriptions belong to the ad):

```
pry(main)> ad.ad_copies
  AdCopy Load (1.5ms)  SELECT `anuncios_textos`.* FROM `anuncios_textos` WHERE `anuncios_textos`.`ad_id` = 1241
  AdCopy Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  `anuncios_textos`.* FROM `anuncios_textos` WHERE `anuncios_textos`.`ad_id` = 1241 LIMIT 11
=> #<AdCopy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x3ffc6d8fc498>
```

What I get here is already confusing to me because I don't know what `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` is.

So the final step is to try get the first description to show:

```
pry(main)> ad.ad_copies.first
  AdCopy Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  `anuncios_textos`.* FROM `anuncios_textos` WHERE `anuncios_textos`.`ad_id` = 1241 ORDER BY `anuncios_textos`.`id_anuncio` ASC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'anuncios_textos.ad_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `anuncios_textos`.* FROM `anuncios_textos` WHERE `anuncios_textos`.`ad_id` = 1241 ORDER BY `anuncios_textos`.`id_anuncio` ASC LIMIT 1
from /Users/okmantis/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `_query'
```

And here's where the problem arises. How am I able to get access to the descriptions belonging to my ad?

Here are my models:

```
class Ad < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "anuncios"
  has_many :ad_copies
  has_many :ad_addresses
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: 'id_anuncio'
  has_many :magazines
  has_many :categories, through: :relationships
  belongs_to :user
end

class AdCopy < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "anuncios_textos"
  self.primary_key = "id_anuncio"
  belongs_to :ad, foreign_key: "id_anuncio", optional: true
  belongs_to :language, foreign_key: "id_idioma", optional: true
end
```

And schema table for model Ad (Spanish: anuncios):

```
create_table "anuncios", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "empresa", null: false
    t.string "tel", null: false
    t.string "fax_principal", null: false
    t.string "movil_principal", null: false
    t.string "email_principal", null: false
    t.string "web", null: false
    t.string "facebook", null: false
    t.string "horario_v_principal", null: false
    t.string "horario_i_principal", null: false
    t.string "direccion_principal", null: false
    t.string "poblacion_principal", null: false
    t.string "activo", limit: 2, null: false
    t.string "tam_anuncio", null: false
    t.string "twitter", null: false
    t.string "link", limit: 2, null: false
    t.string "general", limit: 2, null: false
    t.string "isla", limit: 10, null: false
    t.string "subtitulo", null: false
    t.string "comentario", null: false
    t.datetime "modificacion", null: false
    t.integer "promo1", default: 0, null: false
    t.integer "promo2", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "instagram", null: false
    t.string "tel2", null: false
    t.string "tel3", null: false
    t.string "tel4", null: false
    t.string "movil2", null: false
    t.string "movil3", null: false
    t.string "movil4", null: false
  end
```

And schema table for model AdCopy (Spanish: anuncios_textos):

```
create_table "anuncios_textos", primary_key: ["id_anuncio", "id_idioma"], options: "ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "id_anuncio", null: false
    t.integer "id_idioma", null: false
    t.text "descripcion", null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I forgot to set the foreign-key inside the Ad model to 'id_anuncio'. If you don't explicitly tell rails that the the name of the foreign-key column is different then it will just call it by the models name + id: `ad_id`. You can see this in the error inside the console: `WHERE anuncios_textos.ad_id`.

My the Ad model must therefore have this:

```
class Ad < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "anuncios"
  has_many :ad_copies, foreign_key: 'id_anuncio'
  [...]
end
```